# Updating a div in the succes event of an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am executing 3 nested synchronous jQuery Ajax calls. **Inside the success event handler of the inner most Ajax call I have updated a div on the HTML page. This is not taking effect** on the HTML page until all the calls get completed.

My idea is to give updates to the users on the page about the progress of the process.

The inner most Ajax call uses the information from the above 2 Ajax calls. Thats why if I execute the Ajax calls synchronously it gets wrong data for the inner most Ajax call due to the `for loops` get executed earlier than the main inner most Ajax call gets completed.

Please look at these lines of code in the below sample code:

```
// ISSUE: This line of code takes effect on the HTML page after all the ajax calls get completed
$("<label>" + responseText + "</label><br />").appendTo('#DlgHdBodyContainer');
```

**Sample code:**

```
        //Asynchronous AJAX function to Retrieve a CRM record using OData
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: odataUri,
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                //Specifying this header ensures that the results will be returned as JSON.
                XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
                var customObjects1 = data.d.results;

                for (var i = 0; i < customObjects1.length; i++) {
                    var CustomObject1Id = customObjects1[i].cc_CustomObject1Id;
                    var ActivityId = customObjects1[i].Activity.Id;
                    var CustomObject1Name = customObjects1[i].Name;

                    if (customObjects1[i].Activity.Id != null) {

                        //Asynchronous AJAX function to Retrieve a CRM record using OData
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: odataUri,
                            async: false,
                            beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                                //Specifying this header ensures that the results will be returned as JSON.
                                XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                            },
                            success: function (data2, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {

                                if (data2.d.results.length > 0) {

                                    var CustomLists = data2.d.results;

                                    var ODATA_EntityCollection = "/cc_cloudcalltransactionsSet";

                                    for (var i = 0; i < CustomLists.length; i++) {

                                        //debugger;
                                        var CustomListId = CustomLists[0].ItemId

                                        var pageNum = "1";

                                        while (pageNum != "-1") {

                                            var AjaxObject = new Object();
                                            AjaxObject.cc_type = {
                                                Value: 21
                                            };
                                            AjaxObject.cc_PIN = pageNum;
                                            AjaxObject.cc_callhash = CustomObject1Id + "," + ActivityId + "," + CustomListId; // 300 characters max

                                            //Parse the entity object into JSON
                                            jsonEntity = window.JSON.stringify(AjaxObject);

                                            //Asynchronous AJAX function to Create a CRM record using OData
                                            $.ajax({
                                                type: "POST",
                                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                                dataType: "json",
                                                url: ODATA_ENDPOINT + ODATA_EntityCollection,
                                                async: false,
                                                data: jsonEntity,
                                                beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                                                    //Specifying this header ensures that the results will be returned as JSON.
                                                    XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                                                },
                                                success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {

                                                    var NewCRMRecordCreated = data["d"];

                                                    pageNum = NewCRMRecordCreated.cc_PIN;
                                                    var responseText = NewCRMRecordCreated.cc_Response;

                                                    //alert(responseText);

                                                    // ISSUE: This line of code takes effect on the HTML page after all the ajax calls get completed
                                                    $("<label>" + responseText + "</label><br />").appendTo('#DlgHdBodyContainer');
                                                },
                                                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                                                    pageNum = "-1";
                                                    return;
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                            }
                        });

                    };

                }

            },
            error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            }
        });
```

**Updated code:**
As suggested by **mplungjan** I updated the code below. I placed the inner-most Ajax call outside the two Ajax calls on which it was dependent. I placed the code to update the div `Updatediv("some string");` at different places in the code. Still the page is updating only after the code completes and the browser is returned with the control.

Is there any way to udpate the page as soon as `UpdateDiv` is executed?

```
// Send each list to Api
for (var i = 0; i < objLists.length; i++) {

    var list = objLists[i];

    var pageNum = "1";

    var responseText = "";

    Updatediv("Synch process started");

    while (pageNum != "-1") {

        Updatediv("Processing page number " + pageNum);

        var CRMObject = new Object();
        CRMObject.cc_type = {
            Value: 21
        };
        CRMObject.cc_PIN = pageNum;
        CRMObject.cc_callhash = list.CustomObject1Id + "," + list.ActivityId + "," + list.listId; // cc_callhash is 300 characters max

        //Parse the entity object into JSON
        jsonEntity = window.JSON.stringify(CRMObject);

        //Asynchronous AJAX function to Create a CRM record using OData
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: ODATA_ENDPOINT + ODATA_EntityCollection,
            async: false,
            data: jsonEntity,
            beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                //Specifying this header ensures that the results will be returned as JSON.
                XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {

                var NewCRMRecordCreated = data["d"];

                pageNum = NewCRMRecordCreated.cc_PIN;
                responseText = NewCRMRecordCreated.cc_Response;
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                pageNum = "-1";
                return;
            }
        });

        Updatediv(responseText);


    } // END:  while (pageNum != "-1")

} // END: for (var i = 0; i < objLists.length; i++)

function Updatediv(responseText)
{
    $("<label>" + responseText + "</label><br />").appendTo('#DlgHdBodyContainer');

}
```

Comment: Why are you doing "3 nested synchronous jQuery Ajax calls"? You should really use `promises` for something like that

Comment: What is the problem ? You say : // ISSUE: This line of code takes effect on the HTML page after all the ajax calls get completed `$("<label>" + responseText + "</label><br />").appendTo('#DlgHdBodyContainer');` is in last ajax success method

Comment: @BenjaminPoignant I want to update the div on the page as soon as each inner-most ajax call returns with the success.

Comment: @DelightedD0D Sorry for being dumb, I didn't get what these `promises` are?

Comment: So move `$("<label>" + responseText + "</label><br />").appendTo('#DlgHdBodyContainer');` in first ajax success method ? But if you need responseText  from last ajax, i dont  really undertsand. @DelightedD0D you right, an example : http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/making-promises-with-jquery-deferred.html

Comment: Why do you have `async: false,` set?

Comment: You cannot do what you are trying in the way you are trying it. You need to pass the pageNum to a function that runs in the success and not using a traditional loop

Comment: Also make ONE call to odataUri instead of nesting 2

Comment: @mplungjan Could you please modify my sample code to reflect what you are recommending?

Comment: @DelightedD0D Because if I execute the Ajax calls synchronously it gets wrong data for the inner most Ajax call due to the for loops get executed earlier than the main inner most Ajax call gets completed.

Comment: You need to set up counters, `var customObjectCounter,customListCounter;` - then when calling the first ajax, set the first counter to the length of the result, move the loop content into a function `function processCustomObject() { if (customObjectCounter<=0) return; customObjectCounter--; content of loop with processCustomObject() in success; };`  same for the inner loop but there you need to do `function processListObject() { if (customListCounter<=0) {; processCustomObject(); return; } customListCounter--; content of inner loop with  processListObject() in success; };`

Comment: @mplungjan You mean to store data from the above two calls in array objects and then run all the calls asynchronously?

Comment: Yes. You have the arrays, just save them each time

Comment: @mplungjan and all ... ! I have udpated the code as mplungjan suggested. See in the OP above. Still the web page is updated with the text only when the browser gets the control. Is there any way to reflect the changes as soon as UpdateDiv() is called?

Comment: If you call updatediv with new data it should update each time. If not try `setTimeout(function() { processCustomObject));},10);` to give the browser a breather

Comment: Could you please point which code is need to be run in timeout in my updated code sample? By the way process itself is around 1+ minute long. Isn't this enough for browser breathing?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$("<label>" + responseText + "</label><br />").appendTo('#DlgHdBodyContainer').hide().show();
```

to force a redraw.